# Why php imagefill always black?

Tags: php, image, png

This is driving me mad. I would really appreciate if you told me any idea about why I see this square in red color just in my local xampp installation. If I run the code in the remote server (http://www.arreglaordenador.com/numberimage2.php) I see the square in black color instead of red. Do you have any ideas?

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// sets background to red
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, that is the example from the docs, so it would suggest something is broken with your remote servers installation. Does it have the most up to date GD library built in, with PNG support?

Comment: Try setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and remove all lines from `header()` to the end. Is there any output?

Comment: Does the problem still persists if you change `imagecreatetruecolor()` to `imagecreate()`?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have used `imagecreatetruecolor()` function to create image and your GD version has bugs. `imagecreatetruecolor()` won't override by some color function in some GD versions(I don't remember which). You have two solutions.

1. Ask your hosting service to upgrade GD to latest stable version.

or

1. Use `imagecreate()` function to create image identifier instead `imagecreatetruecolor()`.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks! Helped me with my issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try allocating a different colour first?

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
```

I don't exactly see why, but this looks like a transparency issue to me (i.e. red being selected as a transparent colour for some reason).

Most probably, this is due to different GD versions. Can you compare which one you have locally and which one remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [`imagecreatetruecolor()` documentation](http://www.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor), your server probably doesn't have the correct version of the GD image library installed.

Comment: He is getting a 100x100 image and no warning, so it can hardly be the function missing altogether.

Comment: How do you know he's not getting a warning?

Comment: Correct != any.  Perhaps his PHP version is using the system GD instead of the bundled GD?

Comment: @Jordan: Because he is linking to a live PNG example (see above). If imagecreatetruecolor() were missing, he would get a fatal error and no image.

Comment: For certain versions of PHP, it only raises a warning, not a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a GD issue on your server because your code works just fine on both my local WAMP and on my hosting account.